Are there any Hadith which gives detail about Haman?
The Quran gives limited information about Haman. Is there any Hadith which presents more information about him? I cannot find any direct hadith from the Prophet pbuh but I think there would be some Mawquf hadiths available.

From the Sunnah I only found this hadith
‘Abdallah b. ‘Amr b. al-‘As said that the Prophet mentioned prayer one day saying, “If anyone keeps to it, it will be light, evidence and salvation for him on the day of resurrection; but if anyone does not keep to it, it will not be for him light, evidence, or salvation, and on the day of resurrection he will be associated with Qarun, Pharaoh, Haman, 1 and Ubayy b. Khalaf”2

These three are mentioned together in Al-Qur’an, 29:39; 40:24. A longer account is given of Qarun in 28:76 ff. Haman is mentioned also in 28:38. The Old Testament gives the story of Korah (Qarun) in Numbers, Chap. 16, and of Haman in Esther, Chaps, 3 ff.
Ubayy had been an enemy of the Prophet in Mecca. Ubayy had said he would kill him, but the Prophet replied that if God willed he would kill Ubayy. At the battle of Uhud (3 A H.) Ubayy received a scratch, and remembering the Prophet’s words, he felt sure he was going to die. He died at Sarif, about six miles from Mecca, as he was returning home. See the Cairo edition of as-Sira an-nabawiya by Ibn Hisham, 1355/1936, vol.3, p. 89.

Ahmad, Darimi, and Baihaqi in Shu'ab al-lman transmitted it.
Reference    : Mishkat al-Masabih 578
